# How to integrate instamojo payment gateway in Spring Mvc, actually integration code is missing

Tags: java

I want to know about integration of instamojo payment gateway i SpringMvc,
I am not able to find redirection code to payment link

I have code of github
https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-java

Redirectional Code is missing

```
PaymentOrder order = new PaymentOrder();
order.setName("John Smith");
order.setEmail("john.smith@gmail.com");
order.setPhone("12345678790");
order.setCurrency("INR");
order.setAmount(9D);
order.setDescription("This is a test transaction.");
order.setRedirectUrl("http://www.someexample.com");
order.setWebhookUrl("http://www.someurl.com/");
order.setTransactionId("dxg234");
```

Order code is here but redirection code is missing. Thanks in advance.
I hope anyone can help me out who has already integrated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have proper working code in github, you can download the code and do the work.

https://github.com/s4satishverma/instamojo-java

in case of any issue, you can follow this youtube video as well.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1zSSdBl7uA&t=4s

this will you step by step integration

Comment: please try this, you will 100% solutions